# str.findall to return the value, if one element is found

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find a number in a string and return it as int. There are only two variants: either the number doesn't appear or appears only once. Currently I do this by this code:

```
df['rating'] = pd.to_numeric(df['rating'].astype(str).str.findall('(\d+)').apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x) > 0 else np.nan), errors='coerce')
df['rating'] = pd.Series(df['rating'], dtype=pd.Int32Dtype())
```

But I'm pretty sure the code is not optimal and I can do this shorter. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for match first value else missing value first, then convert to `float`s and last to `intgers with NaNs`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'rating':['asas','ds5dd87','sd223d']})

df['rating'] = df['rating'].astype(str).str.extract('(\d+)').astype(float).astype('Int64')
```

Solution with [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) is similar, only for get first value is use `str[0]`:

```
df['rating']=df['rating'].astype(str).str.findall('(\d+)').str[0].astype(float).astype('Int64')

print (df)
  rating
0    NaN
1      5
2    223
```